# Merge rows in spark scala Dataframe and apply aggregate function

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following Dataframe:

```
| notification_id|       el1|       el2|is_deleted| 
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|notificationId1|element1_1|element1_2|     false| 
|notificationId2|element2_1|element2_2|     false| 
|notificationId3|element3_1|element3_2|     false| 
|notificationId1|      null|      null|      true| 
|notificationId4|      null|      null|      true| 
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The primary key in this example is `notification_id`.

- The rows that have `is_deleted = true`, always have null values for other column except primary key.
- The rows with `is_deleted = false` have a unique primary key.

I would like to merge the rows with the same primary key in order to obtain dataframe with merged `is_delete` column:

```
| notification_id|       el1|       el2|is_deleted| 
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|notificationId1|element1_1|element1_2|      true| 
|notificationId2|element2_1|element2_2|     false| 
|notificationId3|element3_1|element3_2|     false| 
|notificationId4|      null|      null|      true| 
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the primary key and use an `any()` aggregator on the `is_deleted` column, which will yield `true` if any of the rows with the same primary key have a `true` value for `is_deleted`:

```scala
val df_result = df_in.groupBy("notification_id").agg(
  first("el1", ignoreNulls = true).alias("el1"),
  first("el2", ignoreNulls = true).alias("el2"),
  expr("any(is_deleted)").alias("is_deleted")
)
```